# How to upload image to my thumb folder from youtube image url

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

i use this function to get binary data from youtube image url. but after changing the api v2 into api v3 the function i have used in past not longer work. the function did not return any values. please help me to solve this problem.

```
<?php

$thumbnail_link = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/s4bw0HQotfU/0.jpg';


if ( function_exists('curl_init') ) 
    {

        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 0;
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $thumbnail_link);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

        // Getting binary data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

        $image = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo $image; //this will return an empty data why is it?



        //  create & save image;
        $img_res = @imagecreatefromstring($image);
        if($img_res === false)
            return FALSE;

        $img_width = imagesx($img_res);
        $img_height = imagesy($img_res);

        $resource = @imagecreatetruecolor($img_width, $img_height);

        if( function_exists('imageantialias'))
        {
            @imageantialias($resource, true); 
        }

        @imagecopyresampled($resource, $img_res, 0, 0, 0, 0, $img_width, $img_height, $img_width, $img_height);
        @imagedestroy($img_res);

        switch($ext)
        {
            case ".gif":
                //GIF
                @imagegif($resource, $upload_path . $thumb_name);
            break;
            case ".jpg":
                //JPG
                @imagejpeg($resource, $upload_path . $thumb_name);
            break;  
            case ".png":
                //PNG
                @imagepng($resource, $upload_path . $thumb_name);
            break;
        }


    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your thumbnail link i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/s4bw0HQotfU/0.jpg does not exist.

You can use the v3 API to get the correct thumbnail urls:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

In the above case it would be GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=s4bw0HQotfU&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Then you process the results to get the available thumbnails:

```
"thumbnails": {
 "default": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/s4bw0HQotfU/default.jpg",
  "width": 120,
  "height": 90
 },
 "medium": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/s4bw0HQotfU/mqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 320,
  "height": 180
 },
 "high": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/s4bw0HQotfU/hqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 480,
  "height": 360
 },
 "standard": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/s4bw0HQotfU/sddefault.jpg",
  "width": 640,
  "height": 480
 },
 "maxres": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/s4bw0HQotfU/maxresdefault.jpg",
  "width": 1280,
  "height": 720
 }
},
```